# Сумма в зависимости от цены и количества в input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Интересует такой вопрос: как правильно посчитать сумму (общую цену) в зависимости от определенной цены и кол-ва введенного в поле input? Есть код, как изменять значение в поле, но вот посчитать сумму как то не получается корректно.

jQuery

```
//button input 
var sum = parseInt($('.sum_price').text());
$('.degr').click(function(){
    var vI = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    if(vI > 0){
        vI --;
        $(this).parent().find('input').val(vI);
    }           
    var pr_m = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find($('.price_sp')).text())*vI;
});         
$('.incr').click(function(){
    var vI = $(this).parent().find('input').val(); 
    vI++;
    $(this).parent().find('input').val(vI);
    var pr_p = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find($('.price_sp')).text())*vI;
});
```

Писал сам jQuery, может кому пригодится. Особо большого опыта нету :)

HTML

```
<p>Стоимость заказа: <span class="sum_price">0</span> руб.</p>
<p>Детали заказа:</p>
<table class="form_goods_order">
<tr>
<td class="name_goods">Набор экономного болельщика</td>
<td class="price_goods"><span class="price_sp">695</span> р.</td>
<td class="count"><img src="images/count_left.gif" title="Уменьшить" alt="Уменьшить" class="degr"/><input type="text" name="nab1" id="nab1" value="0" /><img src="images/count_right.gif" title="Увеличить" alt="Увеличить" class="incr" /></td>
</tr>
```

Пример работы на [сайте](http://www.eurocap2012.ru/), если нажать на кнопку купить.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum=0;
$('.form_goods_order tr').each(function(){
sum += parseInt($(this).find('.price_sp').text())*parseInt($(this).find('input').val());
});
alert(sum);
```

**upd:**

```
function get_sum(){
    var sum=0;
    $('.form_goods_order tr').each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).find('.price_sp').text())*parseInt($(this).find('input').val());
    });
    return sum;
}
//button input 
        $('.degr').click(function(){
                var $t=$(this).parent().find('input');
                var vI = Math.abs(parseInt($t.val()));
                $t.val(vI?--vI:0);
                $('.sum_price').html(get_sum());

       });         
      $('.incr').click(function(){
            var $t=$(this).parent().find('input');
            var vI = Math.abs(parseInt($t.val())); 
            $t.val(vI?++vI:1);
            $('.sum_price').html(get_sum());
      });
```

Comment: не то. необходимо чтобы сумма динамически изменялась по клику на кнопки больше и меньше

Comment: дак оберните этот код в функцию и вызывайте её каждый раз при клике.

Comment: @SnowMan как то так

Comment: спс. работает)